how To keep the cursor in a textbox in a userform?
I am using below code in the userform to scan the sku barcodes and keep the records in the specific coulumn, but once I scanned the barcode the cursor not stable in the textbox. I wanted to keep the cursor always in the text box.
Private Sub TextBox2_AfterUpdate()

Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = TextBox2.Value
TextBox2.Value = ""

userform1.TextBox2.SetFocus

End Sub



Where does the focus go after you scan a barcode?  maybe the other controls on the form need tabstop=false

Check the documentation on your barcode scanner.  They almost always have a setup sheet with a bunch of barcodes that you can scan to set up your scanner.  Quite often there will be the option available to change what happens after the barcode is sucessfully scanned.  There may be an option to do nothing after the scan.

Another option would be to setup your scanner to pass "ENTER" after a successful scan.  Then have your textbox set to be Multiline.  After each scan, you would get a new line in your textbox, but you should stay in it.

Since there can be multiple instances of any given userform running, it's always safer to use (eg) Me.TextBox2.SetFocus instead of using the name of the form (which always refers to the default instance)

In this example the next control in the TAB order CoomandButton1
Since after ENTER pressed and all events are handled, Excel automatically move the insertion point to the next control. The Enter event replace back the focus.
Private Sub CommandButton1_Enter()
UserForm1.TextBox1.SetFocus

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = TextBox1.Value
TextBox1.Value = ""



End Sub



But I dont want to press the enter button.

Your barcode reader does it.

Trying with barcode reader but it didnt happen
